# executable .jar - missing functionality

Tags: java, jar, runtime-error

I am creating a program for my exam in programming on first semester of my education. It should show the user the time in Copenhagen and 6 other cities (in other timezones). The user should also be able to add cities to the list. I'm writing the program in JAVA (source code provided below). The application is running fine when I run it from eclipse, but when I export it to a .jar file some of the functionality doesn't work. Here is how the program runs from eclipse (and how it should run):[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jP2C.jpg)

When I run it from the .jar file the program won't submit the entered cityname (the program stays at screen 3). It's not that the application stops or get stuck. I can still edit the text fild and press the "Show Time"-button - there's just no reaction from pressing the "Add City"-button (or pressing Enter when focus is in the text field which should also add the entered city to the list).

I have used classes from the JodaTime library (added to the build path).

I export the project from eclipse as a "Runnable JAR file" (I have also tried to export as a "JAR file" but that gives me an error when I run it so I guess that's definitely not the way to do it :P). I have tried all 3 options for "Library handling" when choosing "Runnable JAR file" which are:

1. "Extract required libraries into generated JAR"
2. "Package required libraries into generated JAR"
3. "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR"

The result is the same for the first 2, in the third case when I open the .jar nothing happens.

I have no idea what the source of the problem is. Please help me :-)

### Update!

I think it might be something with the class Capitalize that I made for another project. When I comment out the code where that class is used the program runs fine. I just don't get what it is :S

Okay so I deleted the part with my class from the other project and instead I implemented a new method in this project to do the job. DONE!

Thanks all.

Regards Joakim

Source code:

```
/**
 * This class sets up a window with which a user can interact with a GUI to get the current time in
 * Copenhagen, London, New York, Helsinki, Beijing, San Francisco, New Delhi and Tokyo. The user can
 * also add a new city and its GMT offset to the list where the current time in the new city also
 * will be shown.
 * 
 * @author Joakim
 * @version 1
 * 
 */
public class MyTimeZone
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    MyTimeZone timezone = new MyTimeZone();
}

// Timezone stuff
private DateTime time;
private DateTimeZone selectedTimeZone;

// Graphical stuff
private JFrame window;
private JPanel windowpanel;
private JComboBox<GMTHours> gmtHBox;
private JComboBox<GMTMinutes> gmtMBox;
private JTextField input;
private JTextArea output;
private TreeMap<String, DateTime> outputValues;

/**
 * Sets up the default window in a JFrame.
 */
private MyTimeZone()
{
    window = new JFrame();
    windowpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    setUpPanel();
    window.setContentPane(windowpanel);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(420, 300));
    window.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Sets up the JPanel that will be displayed in a JFrame
 */
private void setUpPanel()
{
    JPanel north = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel south = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    windowpanel.add(north, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    windowpanel.add(south, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    // "Show Time"-button
    JButton showTime = new JButton("Show Time");
    showTime.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            updateTextArea();
            input.setEditable(true);
        }

    });
    north.add(showTime);

    // Output text-area
    output = new JTextArea();
    output.setEditable(false);
    outputValues = new TreeMap<String, DateTime>();
    setDefaultTexts();
    JScrollPane outputTextArea = new JScrollPane(output);
    outputTextArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    windowpanel.add(outputTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Input text-field
    input = new JTextField();
    input.setEditable(false);
    input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
    input.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            try 
            {
                String inputString = input.getText();
                addCity(inputString);
                updateTextArea();
                input.setText("");
                gmtHBox.setSelectedItem(GMTHours.ZERO);
                gmtMBox.setSelectedItem(GMTMinutes.ZERO);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                output.setText(e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    south.add(input);

    // Drop-down menus
    gmtHBox = new JComboBox<GMTHours>();
    gmtHBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    for (GMTHours gmtH : GMTHours.values())
    {
        gmtHBox.addItem(gmtH);
    }
    gmtHBox.setSelectedItem(GMTHours.ZERO);
    south.add(gmtHBox);
    south.add(new JLabel(":"));
    gmtMBox = new JComboBox<GMTMinutes>();
    gmtMBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));
    for (GMTMinutes gmtM : GMTMinutes.values())
    {
        gmtMBox.addItem(gmtM);
    }
    south.add(gmtMBox);

    // "Add City"-button
    JButton addCity = new JButton("Add City");
    addCity.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            try 
            {
                String inputString = input.getText();
                addCity(inputString);
                updateTextArea();
                input.setText("");
                gmtHBox.setSelectedItem(GMTHours.ZERO);
                gmtMBox.setSelectedItem(GMTMinutes.ZERO);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                output.setText(e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    south.add(addCity);

}

/**
 * Updates the output text area. Is called everytime the user adds a city.
 */
private void updateTextArea()
{
    output.setText("");
    Set<Entry<String, DateTime>> set = outputValues.entrySet();
    Iterator<Entry<String, DateTime>> i = set.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry<String, DateTime> me = i.next();
        DateTime newTime = new DateTime(me.getValue().getZone());
        outputValues.put(me.getKey(), newTime);
        output.append(me.getKey() + ": " + getTimeString(newTime));
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a city (string) and its time to the TreeMap of cities
 * that has to be written in the output area.
 * 
 * @param inputString The city (string) to be added
 */
private void addCity(String inputString)
{
    Capitalize cap = new Capitalize();
    inputString = cap.capitalizeString(inputString);  // See documentation for more
                                                            // info about class Capitalize
    selectedTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(
            gmtHBox.getItemAt(gmtHBox.getSelectedIndex()).offset,
            gmtMBox.getItemAt(gmtMBox.getSelectedIndex()).offset);
    time = new DateTime(selectedTimeZone);
    outputValues.put(inputString, time);
}

/**
 * This method sets the default values of the output text area (introduction) and 
 * fills the TreeMap with the default cities and their time
 */
private void setDefaultTexts()
{
    output.setText("When you click the button above the current time in Copenhagen is\n"
            + "shown here as well as the time in 6 other cities along with their GMT\n"
            + "time differences shown in parantheses.\n\n" 
            + "After you have clicked 'Show Time' you can also submit cities to the\n" 
            + "list yourself by typing the name of the city in the text-field beneath and\n" 
            + "choosing the GMT offset in [hours]:[minutes] in the dropdown menus.");

    time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Copenhagen"));
    outputValues.put("Copenhagen", time);

    time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
    outputValues.put("London", time);

    time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
    outputValues.put("New York", time);

    time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Helsinki"));
    outputValues.put("Helsinki", time);

    time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Hong_Kong"));
    outputValues.put("Beijing", time);

    time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Vancouver"));
    outputValues.put("San Francisco", time);

    time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
    outputValues.put("New Delhi", time);

    time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Tokyo"));
    outputValues.put("Tokyo", time);

}

/**
 * Converts a DateTime object to a string with the given time and the offset from the given 
 * timezone to the Greenwich Main Time.
 * 
 * @param time A DateTime object from which you want a string representing the time.
 * @return A string of the format: "02:30 (GMT-3:15)" if the time specified in the DateTime
 *         object is 2:30 and the offset is 3 hours and 15 minutes behind GMT.
 */
private String getTimeString(DateTime time)
{
    String completeTimeString = "";
    if (time.hourOfDay().get() < 10)
        completeTimeString = "0" + time.hourOfDay().get();
    else
        completeTimeString = "" + time.hourOfDay().get();
    completeTimeString += ":";
    if (time.minuteOfHour().get() == 0)
        completeTimeString += "0" + time.minuteOfHour().get();
    else
        completeTimeString += "" + time.minuteOfHour().get();

    completeTimeString += " (GMT";
    DateTime gmt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT0"));
    int offsetInMinutes = time.getZone().getOffset(gmt.getMillis()) / 60000;
    if (offsetInMinutes > 0)
        completeTimeString += "+";
    completeTimeString += offsetInMinutes / 60;
    if (offsetInMinutes % 60 != 0)
    {
        if (offsetInMinutes < 0)
            offsetInMinutes = offsetInMinutes * (-1);
        completeTimeString += ":" + offsetInMinutes % 60 + ")\n";
    }
    else
        completeTimeString += ")\n";
    return completeTimeString;
}



/**
 * An enum for all the GMT hourly offset values
 * 
 * @author Joakim
 * 
 */
private enum GMTHours
{
    MINUS12(-12), MINUS11(-11), MINUS10(-10), MINUS9(-9), MINUS8(-8), MINUS7(-7), MINUS6(-6), 
            MINUS5(-5), MINUS4(-4), MINUS3(-3), MINUS2(-2), MINUS1(-1), ZERO(0), PLUS1(1), 
            PLUS2(2), PLUS3(3), PLUS4(4), PLUS5(5), PLUS6(6), PLUS7(7), PLUS8(8), PLUS9(9), 
            PLUS10(10), PLUS11(11), PLUS12(12);

    private int offset;

    GMTHours(int offset)
    {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "GMT";
        switch (offset)
        {
        case -1: s += "-1"; break;
        case -2: s += "-2"; break;
        case -3: s += "-3"; break;
        case -4: s += "-4"; break;
        case -5: s += "-5"; break;
        case -6: s += "-6"; break;
        case -7: s += "-7"; break;
        case -8: s += "-8"; break;
        case -9: s += "-9"; break;
        case -10: s += "-10"; break;
        case -11: s += "-11"; break;
        case -12: s += "-12"; break;
        case 0: s += "0"; break;
        case 1: s += "+1"; break;
        case 2: s += "+2"; break;
        case 3: s += "+3"; break;
        case 4: s += "+4"; break;
        case 5: s += "+5"; break;
        case 6: s += "+6"; break;
        case 7: s += "+7"; break;
        case 8: s += "+8"; break;
        case 9: s += "+9"; break;
        case 10: s += "+10"; break;
        case 11: s += "+11"; break;
        case 12: s += "+12"; break;
        }
        return s;
    }
}

/**
 * An enum for all the GMT minutely offset values
 * 
 * @author Joakim
 *
 */
private enum GMTMinutes
{
    ZERO(0), FIFTEEN(15), THIRTY(30), FORTYFIVE(45);

    private int offset;

    GMTMinutes(int offset)
    {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "";
        switch (offset)
        {
        case 0: s = "00"; break;
        case 15: s = "15"; break;
        case 30: s = "30"; break;
        case 45: s = "45"; break;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely getting an exception because the Jar files with the Jode time library are not on your classpath at runtime. And further, you probably don't have code (I did not look at your code in detail) to catch exceptions you don't expect and give error reporting. So the exception is just swallowed. I recommend fixing that before you turn in your assignment.

Another suggestion is to remotely debug the program using Eclipse so that you can see exactly what it's going when you are running it from the command line. [Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) is a pretty good description for how to do it.

Comment: You are right about the exception catching :) How do I make sure the JodaTime library is in the classpath at runtime?

Comment: java -cp joda.jar -jar yourjar.jar

Comment: Or if it's to be run on Windows, a short-cut that does this for you.

Comment: I have also used a static method from a class I have made myself earlier on (in another project). Does this also need to be added to the classpath at runtime?
And also the application have to be able to run on Windows, Mac and Linux. So I can't use the batch file after all. What do I do then?

Comment: Yes, you will need all classes that you touch on the classpath. Either put it in your jar or reference the other jar files. If you have multiple files on the classpath it's jar1.jar;jar2.jar;jar3.jar (on windows) and use ":" as a separator on other platforms.

Comment: If it has to run on all platforms, you can make a  .bat file for windows an a shell script for other mac and linux (this is often done), or you can specify the command line from Java and have the user type that in.

Comment: But isn't eclipse supposed to add it to the jar file when I choose "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" when exporting to a .jar-file?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, it should have added all of the Joda classes and anything you depend on as specified by your selected launch configuration. Did you look inside the jar and see what was there. THe "Extract" is the one you want to unpack and add everything.

Comment: If you are not getting what you want in your Jar file, make sure you are using the right launch configuration.

Comment: What I don't get is. How can the program show the time and GMT offset for the 7 default cities, but not add another city to the list, if the program can't use the JodaTime because it's not on the classpath? I use JodaTime to get the current time in a city and also to get the offset from the given timezone to GMT.

Comment: I just extracted it and it was all there (both JodaTime and my own class)

Comment: If everything was in the jar file, then you don't need anything on the classpath. Something else is probably going on with your program unrelated to the classpath issue. If you were able to see anything from the Joda time stuff then you know it's properly available to you.

Comment: I would make sure and have try/catch blocks in your listeners, and also you can debug your program when running outside of Eclipse by attaching to it remotely. Google "remote debugging eclipse" This way you can step through the program as it actually fails.

Comment: I added some more to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add all reqired Java imports, I miss there

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
etc...
```

and maybe you have look at [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) with `DateSpinnerModel` rather than implements `JComboBoxes` for every `Date` parts

I can't resist about your implemantations, sure JodaTime is excelent API, but JSpinner give me

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TimeZoneSpinners {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TimeZoneSpinners().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeUI() {
        final String[] zones = {"Asia/Tokyo", "Asia/Hong_Kong",
            "Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Paris", "Europe/London",
            "America/New_York", "America/Los_Angeles"
        };
        final JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[zones.length];
        final SimpleDateFormat[] formats = new SimpleDateFormat[zones.length];

        SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        model.setValue(date);

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Date date = (Date) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue();
                for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    labels[i].setText(formats[i].format(date));
                }
            }
        });

        SimpleDateFormat format = ((JSpinner.DateEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getFormat();
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[0]));
        format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(zones.length, 2, 4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {
            formats[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            formats[i].setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[i]));

            JLabel label = new JLabel(zones[i]);
            labels[i] = new JLabel("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(labels[i]);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(spinner, "North");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "Center");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

from Java TimeZones

```
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TZShiftTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Assume DST shift happens on a minute boundary,
        // that is, when minutes, seconds, and millis are zero.
        // 60 min./hr. * 24 hr./day * 265 days/yr * about 250 TZs that use DST = 131,400,000 tests
        // to test every minute of every TZ that uses DST for one year
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzzz");
        String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        Arrays.sort(ids);
        long totalElapsed = 0L;
        for (String id : ids) {
            long start;
            long end;
            long elapsed;
            int startYear;
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
            if (!tz.useDaylightTime()) {
                continue;
            }
            Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            start = System.nanoTime();
            cal.setTimeZone(tz);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
            startYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            df.setTimeZone(tz);
            while (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == startYear) {
                tz.inDaylightTime(cal.getTime());
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
            }
            end = System.nanoTime();
            elapsed = end - start;
            totalElapsed += elapsed;
            System.out.printf("%s took %,d ms, total is %,d s%n", tz.getDisplayName(), elapsed / 1000000L, totalElapsed / 1000000000L);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not copy/pasting the imports. They are there of course :-) Otherwise the code would not compile in eclipse

Comment: Thanks for coming with suggestions for the code, but unfortunately I don't have time to remake it at this point. I just need to get the .jar file working.